# Deleting millions of records on SQL Server 14.0

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, delete

I have two tables containing 200 Millions of records each.
I have to delete from them, approximately 70 Millions of records, based on an integer value in a column.

I'm deleting them in chunks of 4000, using the following script:

```
DECLARE @BATCHSIZE INT, @ITERATION INT, @TOTALROWS INT, @MSG VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @STARTTIME DATETIME, @ENDTIME DATETIME

SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY LOW;
SET @BATCHSIZE = 4000
SET @ITERATION = 0 
SET @TOTALROWS = 0 

WHILE @BATCHSIZE>0
BEGIN   
    SET @STARTTIME = GETDATE();

    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    DELETE TOP(@BATCHSIZE)
    FROM [mydb].[dbo].tableA 
    WHERE [mydb].[dbo].tableA.Code not IN (
            SELECT Code
            FROM [mydb].[dbo].TableB)

    SET @BATCHSIZE=@@ROWCOUNT
    SET @ITERATION=@ITERATION+1
    SET @TOTALROWS=@TOTALROWS+@BATCHSIZE
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

    SET @ENDTIME = GETDATE();

    SET @MSG = 'Iteration: ' + CAST(@ITERATION AS VARCHAR) + ' Total deletes:' + CAST(@TOTALROWS AS VARCHAR) + '  >> ' + CAST(DATEDIFF(millisecond, @STARTTIME,@ENDTIME) AS VARCHAR)
    RAISERROR (@MSG, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT
END
```

TableA contains 6 columns, 5 of integers and one NVARCHAR(64).
There is an index on the column Code, and clusterIndex on the PK.
TableB contains only one column, Code,it's a PK.

After running the script for a couple of hrs, it becames very very slow.

At the beginning each iteration was executed in 250ms, then it increase to **2 minutes** after running for some hours.

The database is in simple recovery mode. It's not used by anyone, and it's running on a dedicated machine with 256GB of RAM.

I've tried to rebuild the indexes every hour, Shrink the database (not the file because my user can't) but it's always slow.

If I start to delete the records on another table it has the exact same behaviour, starting very very fast and then increase to slow down after every iteration.

How can I restore the initial conditions? What can I do to improve the delete?
I've tried to

Comment: [Take Care When Scripting Batches](https://michaeljswart.com/2014/09/take-care-when-scripting-batches/)

Comment: @DenisRubashkin Ok, this is how to modify the batch delete, but why now the two tables are so slow? What can I do to restore their read/write speed?

Comment: *The first few batches complete quickly, but later batches gradually get slower as it takes longer and longer to scan the index to find rows to delete. By the time the script gets to the last batch, SQL Server has to delete rows near the very end of the clustered index and to find them, SQL Server has to scan the entire table.* - this info looks absolutely clear. Or what else did you mean asking "why now the two tables are so slow"?

Comment: Sounds like a large enough delete to warrant consideration of just SELECT'ing out the rows you want to keep from the original table INTO a new table, then just drop the old table. This assumes some other factors 1 the system is not highly available, you have a window of time to do this in 2 you have space for 2 copies of the tables. ,etc... things like that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For large deletes in batches, consider specifying a clustered index key range instead of using `TOP` so that a clustered index seek can be used in the plan. Below is an example.

```
DECLARE
      @BATCHSIZE INT = 4000
    , @ITERATION INT = 0
    , @TOTALROWS INT = 0
    , @MSG VARCHAR(500)
    , @STARTTIME DATETIME
    , @ENDTIME DATETIME
    , @StartValue int = 0
    , @EndValue int = 0
    , @MaxValue int = (SELECT MAX(PK) FROM [mydb].[dbo].tableA);

SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY LOW;

WHILE @StartValue <= @MaxValue
BEGIN

    SET @EndValue = @StartValue + @BATCHSIZE;

    SET @STARTTIME = GETDATE();

    DELETE FROM [mydb].[dbo].tableA 
    WHERE [mydb].[dbo].tableA.Code NOT IN (
            SELECT Code
            FROM [mydb].[dbo].TableB
        )
        AND [mydb].[dbo].tableA.PK >= @StartValue
        AND [mydb].[dbo].tableA.PK < @EndValue;

    SET @TOTALROWS=@TOTALROWS+@@ROWCOUNT;
    SET @ITERATION=@ITERATION+1;


    SET @ENDTIME = GETDATE();

    SET @MSG = 'Iteration: ' + CAST(@ITERATION AS VARCHAR) + ' Total deletes:' + CAST(@TOTALROWS AS VARCHAR) + '  >> ' + CAST(DATEDIFF(millisecond, @STARTTIME,@ENDTIME) AS VARCHAR);

    RAISERROR (@MSG, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT;

    SET @StartValue = @EndValue;

END;
GO
```